# Laravel authentication for microservices

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, microservices

I'm planning to make a microservices architecture using `Laravel` as the backend and `VueJs` or maybe `ReactJs` as the frontend. The microservices will consist of

- User authentication service (For authenticating user)
- User management service (To manage organization member database)
- Event management service (For creating organization event)
- Etc.

All of the services will require user request to be authenticated, but using central user database, which is located on `User authentication service.` Eventually, on each web application, it will use at least 2 of the services.

How am I able to authenticate the user before making the request to the specified services? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check out the documentation for how Laravel Authentication works? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication

Comment: Yes I know it well. Using API Token for authenticating doesn't solve my problem since I need to use centralized user data. @FerryKranenburg

Comment: as much as I like the question, its scope is too big for StackOverflow. If you have a question about such major design decisions, SO might not be the place since an answer would be subjective and cannot possibly take into account all the requirements for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Think carefully about your reasoning for developing a distributed system with a microservice architecure. Developing such a system can be complicated and might introduce more problems than it solves for you. You should consider things like code base management, data synchronisation and service availability for example. A standard `monolithic` architecture with the `frontend (Vue/React)` and `backend (API)` as separate projects will be simpler and may provide the flexability you need. Should the need arise in the future to develop a service orientated architecture arise, worry about it then.

That said, typically you wouldn't allow direct access to your services. There would be an `API` gateway which users access and it proxies requests to the relevant service. So your users would make a request to `api.domain.tld/auth/login` which would then be forwarded by the gateway to your `auth` service, process the request and then provide a failure response, or a success response which would include some sort of auth `token` which would be used to authorise subsequent requests to your other services. Sometimes services are aware of each other and can communicate directly if require, other times they use the `API` gateway for service communication.